# Accessing list from Sharepoint Webservice with Sharepoint Online 2013

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to access a list from sharepoint via the web services.

I have tried lots of different web reference URLS for my web service.

The list is found at :

```
example.com/sites/dms/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/Documents/AllItems.aspx
```

the Web service URL I am using now is

```
https://example.com/sites/dms/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
```

Obviously example.com is not the real URL.

when I run the code

```
service.GetList("Documents");
```

I get the error:

> List does not exist.
>   The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.
>   0x82000006

My full code (many things are just for testing purposes):

```
public void UpdateList()
{
    MKLists.Lists service = GetService();

    string targetSite = "https://mywebpage.com/sites/dms";

    using (ClientContext ctx = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext(targetSite))
    {
        if (ctx != null)
        {
            ctx.Load(ctx.Web); // Query for Web
            ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // Execute
            string test = (ctx.Web.Title);
        }
    }

    CookieCollection authCookie = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedCookies(targetSite, 925, 525);

    service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    service.CookieContainer.Add(authCookie);

    XmlNode tester = service.GetList("Documents");
}


    private MKLists.Lists GetService()
    {
        MKLists.Lists myService = new MKLists.Lists();
        myService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        return myService;
    }
```

Comment: Stakoverflow has developed Sharepoint site you should ask it there you will get correct answer more from there.

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
MKLists.Lists service = GetService();
```

with

```
MKLists.Lists service = new MKLists.Lists();
```

i hope this helps.

**Edit**

according to your comment in the answer here is the update @Michael
try changing your targetsite url to

```
string targetSite = "https://mywebpage.com/sites/dms/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
```

hope this time it helps

Comment: sorry. GetServices) is a helper method I have made up. I haved edited question to show this

Answer (score 0):

IT turns out it was to do with the subsites.. and this line solved it:

```
service.Url = "https://mywebpage.com/sites/dms/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found some users with the same issue.

They said that these links below solved that issue. Could you try it?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/12/connecting-to-sharepoint-online-web-services.aspx

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx